# Type mismatch using template in C++

Tags: c++, templates

I've written a class template (in the file `abc.hpp`):

```
template <class Node>
class Edge {
public:
    Edge(Node n1, Node n2):_start(MIN(n1,n2)),_end(MAX(n1,n2)) {};
    Node GetStart ()const {return _start;}
    Node GetEnd ()const {return _end;}
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Edge<Node>& ed)
    {
        os << "(" << ed._start << ", " << ed._end << ")";
        return os;
    }
protected:
    Node _start;
    Node _end;
};
```

And I've written a test program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "abc.hpp"

int main (){
  Edge<int> my_var (1,2);
  Edge<int> my_var2 (1,3);
  int vstart = my_var.GetStart;
  int vend = my_var.GetEnd;
  cout << my_var << " : " << my_var2 << endl;
}
```

When I try to compile it (using devcpp) the compiler puts out an error message regarding the lines `int vstart = my_var.GetStart;` and `int vend = my_var.GetEnd;`

```
argument of type `int(Edge<int>::)() const` does not match `int`
```

What is the problem, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're trying to assign the function to vstart, instead of the result of calling the function:

```
int vstart = my_var.GetStart(); // <- I added () here
int vend = my_var.GetEnd();     // <- and here.
```